# Can I neglect rotation (angular inertia) in inelastic collisions, in the overdamped approximation?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, collision, scattering, approximations

In an overdamped system, "inertia", is neglected. See e.g.,  [When is "Inertia" Negligible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/85976/when-is-inertia-negligible)

Does this mean that in an completely inelastic collision, for example when two disks collide in two dimensions and stick to each-other, I can also neglect the rotation of the joint body due to angular momentum?

Comment: By ignoring inertia do you mean approximate the object as a particle (zero inertia) or as a non-rotating object (infinite size)?

Comment: you can neglect the  „inertia „ if the kinetic energy is much smaller then the potential energy of your system. 

$~ -\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}=-b\dot x$

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. In an overdamped situation, it is assumed velocities change slowly and thus accelerations are almost negligible. But in plastic collisions velocities do change quite abruptly regardless if they are elastic or plastic.

There is just no equivalency here between the two situations. In the equations of motion, you can ignore the mass moment of inertia of a body only if it has fixed (zero or constant) rotational velocity. In the context of collisions, this means the *change* in angular velocity must be negligible also.

Specifically, in the equation below describing the change in rotational velocity due to an impact with impulse $\vec{J} $, when would it be ok to ignore ${\rm I}$?

$$ \Delta \vec{\omega} = {\rm I}^{-1} ( \vec{r} \times \vec{J} ) $$

You can't assume ${\rm I} \approx 0$ (point particle) because the resulting rotation will be infinite. Maybe the assumption ${\rm I} \rightarrow \infty$ (infinite size body) can be made if the geometry of the problem permits it (bullet hitting the earth for example).

The fact that the collision is inelastic, plastic or elastic really only affects the magnitude of impulse, ranging from one value for inelastic collisions to twice that value for elastic collisions.

If you are suggesting that angular momentum plays little part in calculating the impulse and only the mass is important, this is in generally incorrect and only under specific circumstances might apply. For example when two *particles* collide, or when the contact direction goes through or near the center of mass.

Consider two bodies, each with mass $m_1$ and $m_2$, and mass moment of inertia $I_1$ and $I_2$ that are in contact. The perpendicular distance between the contact point and each center of mass is $c_1$ and $c_2$ respectively, then this is how you resolve the contact (simplified 2D version).

$$ \begin{array}{r|l}
\text{impact speed} & v_{\rm imp} = v_1 - v_2 \\
\text{reduced mass} & m^\star = \frac{1}{\tfrac{1}{m_1} + \tfrac{1}{m_2} + \tfrac{c_1^2}{I_1} + \tfrac{c_2^2}{I_2} } \\
\hline
\text{impulse} & J = (1+\epsilon) \,m^\star \, v_{\rm imp} \\
\hline
\text{step in motions} & \Delta v_1 = -\tfrac{1}{m_1} J \\
& \Delta v_2 = +\tfrac{1}{m_2} J \\
& \Delta \omega_1 = -{\rm I}_1^{-1} c_1 J \\
& \Delta \omega_2 = +{\rm I}_2^{-1} c_2 J
\end{array} $$

where $\epsilon$ is the coefficient of restitution. You are proposing that when $\epsilon = 0$ then the moment of inertia can be ignored. **This is not supported by the math** since there is nowhere above where $\epsilon$ is a coefficient of ${\rm I}$ or ${\rm I}^{-1}$ which would cancel out for inelastic collisions.

For the impulse $J$ calculation you see this $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{c^2}{I}}$ type of function and you can argue that when $\frac{1}{m} \gg \frac{c^2}{I}$ then the inertial terms can be ignored. But this is a function of the problem geometry and not if the system is elastic or inelastic.

<sub>See [related post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/730579/392) on the response to impulse on free floating rod.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still not sure though... In the overdamped approximation the reason is the strong stokes friction, which counters the acceleration. The same can be thought of for the angular acceleration due to the impact in the inelastic collision. The viscosity of the fluid in the medium is so high that it that it stops the particles from having inertia. But in principle could also do the same for angular inertia, for the same reason.  Can you show the difference a bit more mathematically pls?  Changing angular momentum is nothing more than $\vec{p}\times\vec{r}$.

Comment: @user1611107 in the context of a fluid if you start from a high velocity and try to cram it through a small nozzle the inertial effects are severe and need to be accounted for, only after the flow has settled into low speeds inertial effects can be ignored.

There is _nothing_ that says the two disks colliding and sticking together will result in slow rotational speeds. Relative to each other yes, but in terms of their angular momentum no. I suggest you work out the equations yourself and see. Use [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/529743/392) for reference.

Comment: Maybe [related post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/730579/392) that shows how the effective mass (reduced mass) between two 3D bodies is calculated. The rotational inertia tensor $\rm I$ goes into this calculation which is a necessary step for evaluating the impulse due to a collision.

Comment: @user1611107 - See above **edit** on my answer expanding much more and providing some equations to support it.